# Trying to do a simple countdown application but counter isn't counting down?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, nstimer

I'm working on Xcode 6 and trying to make a simple countdown app.
My app is really is simple. the UI has a label and a button. when the button is clicked, it should count down from 10.

Here is my code:

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface ViewController : UIViewController

{
    NSInteger count;
    NSTimer *timer;
}

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *timerLabel;

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

-(IBAction)start {
    count = 10;
    timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(timerFired:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
};

-(void)timerFired:(NSTimer *)timer {
    count -=1;
    self.timerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",count];

    if (count == 0) {
        [timer invalidate];
    }

}
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

@end
```

The program compiles fine but when I click the button to start the countdown nothing happens. where did I go wrong?

Edit: thanks a lot guys! problem solved. i spent 3 hours just trying to figure out what i did wrong only to find out it was a silly mistake. agh.
love you stackoverflow!

Comment: is your start method linked with the UIButton's UIControlEventTouchUpInside event?

Comment: Your timer isn't running.  Use [+scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSTimer/scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've set up your firing method properly, but the timer is not actually firing. As [mentioned by Darren](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28335732/trying-to-do-a-simple-countdown-application-but-counter-isnt-counting-down#comment45017682_28335732), you want to use the [`scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSTimer/scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:) constructor as opposed to the [`timerWithTimeInterval`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSTimer/timerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:) constructor, which does not fire unless you specifically call `[NSTimer fire]`.

So, just switch out the old constructor for this:

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(timerFired:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

The timer should then fire properly (every second) and call the associated method:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you should use this NStimer initial method.

```
+ (NSTimer *)scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)ti target:(id)aTarget selector:(SEL)aSelector userInfo:(id)userInfo repeats:(BOOL)yesOrNo;
```

the main problem in your code is that, the

```
+ (NSTimer *)timerWithTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)ti target:(id)aTarget selector:(SEL)aSelector userInfo:(id)userInfo repeats:(BOOL)yesOrNo;
```

did not added your timer to the runloop,so your timer immediately released after one invocation.And the scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval method dealed the runloop things for you.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line in your code

```
timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(timerFired:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

with this line

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(timerFired:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```